# I no longer have smart bash completion for normal user

Tags: linux, bash

I created a new user on our Ubuntu server and I no longer have the bash auto/smart completion (pressing tab once finishes your current phrase if possible. Two tabs give you a `ls`).

Smart complete works fine as root, but I want to enable it for my user.

Comment: Sidenote: pressing tab as of now does an actual tab (6 spaces or so)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `set disable-completion On` in /etc/inputrc (or ~/.inputrc) will disable readline's autocomplete.  That would cause the Tab key to just tab.

Possibly having a shell other than bash could cause autocomplete to not work.

Comment: Ah you nailed it. a quick echo of $SHELL spit back "/bin/sh" -- I switch to bin bash and I'm back in business. Thanks to everyone for the quick help.

Answer (score 2):

Does doing `. /etc/bash_completion` as your user enable completion? If so, you can put it in your `~/.bash_profile` file so that it gets run when you login.

Comment: I don't see an /etc/bash_completion, but I do see /etc/bash.bashrc and a folder called /etc/bash_completion.d/ which contains the files "apatch2.2-common", "debconf" and "insserv" -- any good?

Comment: Have you got the `bash-completion` package installed? If you do `dpkg -l bash-completion` the first two characters should be `ii`. If not, install it with `apt-get install bash-completion`.

Comment: I believe the bash-completion package just extends bash's completion feature, I think that's what's commonly referred to as the smart-completion or Programmable completion.  If I understand correctly, the standard completion isn't working either.

Comment: smart complete works for root, just not for my user.